# Stop MediaPlayer from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I have several fragments playing sounds through MediaPlayer. But I want to stop the mediaplayer once the fragment gets changed. I tried:

- `onDetach()` (Only happens when swiping 2 fragments further.)
- `onDestroy()`
- `onStop()`
  etc.

Is there a way to use the `onTabUnselected` in my fragment? Or to stop the mediaplayer in another fragment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't onPause get called at the appropriate time?

Comment: No, it gets called when I swipe two fragments instead of one fragment

Answer (score 1):

I would implement an interface like this:

```
public interface INoisey {
  public void stopThatNoise();
}
```

then let every fragement that makes a noise implement the interface.
After this you only have to pass any fragement that makes noise to a place which is reachable for you from any fragement, without coupling each fragment with each other. I would use an application class.
Then when a fragement changes it can call the stopThatNoise method on all fragements over the application context.

Or better, i forgot that any fragment you are showing is part of the activity which is in use. Normaly the activity already knows his fragments, so you can call stopThatNoise from there in a better way.

Here is not exactly your case, but the basic idea behind that.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_activitycommunication

Comment: Thanks, will try to figure out how to do that :)